# Open File Managers in remote X

Tags: x11, remote, gui, file-manager

I never need to open a GUI File Managers in remote X, until today. However none of the two File Managers that I have can do that, `pcmanfm-qt` and `thunar`.

Typing them in my remote Xterm, they will just silently exit, without complaining anything. Running an `xterm &` will bring up a remote Xterm in my DISPLAY, which is remote to what it is launching from, just as I expect it.

**UPDATES:**

```bsh
file /usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt
/usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=59192b67bf7c16b0f5ffcf1ca9ce2d71e9d87c1f, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ /usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt &
[1] 2193558
[1]+  Done                    /usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt

$ /usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt  

$ echo $?
0

$ file /usr/bin/thunar
/usr/bin/thunar: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=3bf4e1f43c4c0defc96b87c4f96a09eaa25bd9a2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ thunar --display=localhost:10.0

$ echo $?
0

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish

# -- ^ this is host machine, that I ssh to remotely

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
Release:        10.10
Codename:       buster

# -- ^ this is client machine, that I ssh remotely from
```

Comments?

Comment: `thunar` works here. Perhaps they are started via a script which resets `$DISPLAY`. What happens if you force the display, `--display=<whatever>`? And post the exit code. Other than that, I cannot help.

Comment: Must be so @Bib! I found both `pcmanfm-qt` and `thunar` were actually opened in local (host) DISPLAY. What a coincident that none of the File Managers that I have worked remotely.

Comment: No, not a coincident @Bib. thunar doesn't work even with `--display=<whatever>`. See update in OP.

Comment: Strange indeed. Perhaps there is a resource file which overrides it, but that it a very long shot. Unfortunately I am out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that thunar works at your side, Bib. I've also confirmed that pcmanfm-qt works _reversely_. I.e., Machine B remote to Machine A not OK, but Machine A remote to Machine B OK. So, yeah, strange! Hope someday someone can find some explanation...